# Is it possible to store custom metadata for SSAS objects within SSAS? (for versioning)

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to implement a form of versioning for our company's SQL Analysis Services Databases.

At the moment we have a very simple drop and recreate each time we actually deploy using the [SQLPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/?view=sqlserver-ps) PowerShell module and XMLA, but this causes hindrances when having to reprocess large measure groups because of the database being recreated and we would like to where possible reduce the deployment window since this can impact reprocessing backlog of transactions after deployment is finished since the system needs to catchup again.

So thus i am trying to implement a form of versioning so that only when there is actually a schema or model change would the objects need to be dropped and recreated since our entire deployment process is automated then in those cases we will book a longer deployment slot.

I am trying to find out if there is any functionality that exists within SSAS itself which allows you to maybe store some text value perhaps like a version number of the databases which can then be correlated to whether we need to drop and recreate the SSAS database.

At the moment I could not find anything so my best bet so far is to rely on managing the version number of the database via its related sql database instance so then I use a tracking table within the SQL instance to check if the latest version of this release has already been deployed.

Does anyone know of any method where such custom metadata might be added to the SSAS objects other that trying to modify their names which i would like to avoid.

Does anyone know of something like this perhaps or has anyone dealt with a similar scenario and if yes, how did you approach it?

Comment: I'm fairly confident there's no room for attaching custom metadata properties to objects themselves, but you *could* simply store a hidden (cube-scoped) member in the cube, or even a whole hidden dimension dedicated to tracking the versioning data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did think of using something like a mock member somewhere, in my case the versioning is on SSAS database level not on cube level so i could use something somewhere in the SSAS database to store the version stamp. I would have to rely on something which does not rely on the database being in a processed state necessarily to determine the version number though.

Comment: The database doesn't need to be processed to retrieve its definition, so if the member is a constant in the database script you could fetch it through XMLA... however, that's sufficiently inconvenient that it would no longer be very interesting. You could put all the metadata in a separate cube and process that whenever it's not processed, leaving the rest untouched, though that also seems a bit more involved than you'd really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **Annotations**. Almost all components of SSAS cube have **Annotations** property which is a collection of **Annotation** structures. It is a structure with `Name` property which is a key and string `Value` storing arbitrary string.
Good thing about annotations that its are stored in SSAS metadata and can be retrieved back from server once cube is deployed.

Comment: Hi Ferdipux. thank you for you answer i did some testing with the annotations and its exactly what i was looking for, i can even access the annotations without the database being in a processed state. The only drawback is you would have to manually add the annotation to the XMLA script when we publish a new version of a SSAS db but that does not happen often and with a bit of documentation i am sure we can work around the design aspect of that while this will make deployments much simpler.

Comment: For anyone wanting to use this for a similar purpose your version number or custom annotation can then be retrieved by using the following xmla message

<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">

 <RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>

 <Restrictions>
  <RestrictionList>
   <DatabaseID>SSAS DB Name</DatabaseID>
   <ObjectExpansion>ObjectProperties</ObjectExpansion>
  </RestrictionList>
 </Restrictions>

 <Properties>
  <PropertyList>
  </PropertyList>
 </Properties>

</Discover>